# Create multiple features

Tags: python

I have this script, and I need to modify it so that in one go any number of different buffers around a line(streets) can be calculated, e.g. 50, 100, 200,300 (using loop). These are also supposed to be in different records in the geodatabase (or as shapefiles in another folder). The names of the records to be created should be dynamically determined by a user-requested prefix and the buffer value. I am just getting started with python and I'm stuck with this exercise.
Any ideas?

```
    import arcpy     
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1        
    arcpy.env.workspace = "D:\\default.gdb"    
    ny_Streets = "streets"
    Buff_streets = "Buffer_500"
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis (ny_Streets, Buff_streets, "500 Meters", "FULL", "ROUND", "ALL", "")
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say _buffer sizes_? also this sounds like a homework assignment

Comment: By buffer sizes I mean the buffers  features created around a line feature in ArcGIS pro. This is a homework in form of an exercise, which I sadly can't understand, so I'm searching for help here.

Comment: if `300 Meters` the buffer size or is `Buff_streets`?

Comment: 300 Meters is the buffer size Buff_streets is the output feature class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you are looking for, sounds like you need something like the following:

```
import arcpy     

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1        
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:\\default.gdb"    

ny_Streets = "streets"
for buff in (50, 100, 200, 300):
    Buff_streets = "Buff_{}".format(buff)
    buff_dist = "{} Meters".format(buff)
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis (ny_Streets, Buff_streets, buff_dist, "FULL", "ROUND", "ALL", "")
```

Comment: Yes, it worked, can you explain to me what the function of `.format(buff)` is in the code?

Comment: it formats the string with the value in the parens, in this case the different buffer sizes